# How train in google cloud without uploading the data?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Im training a CNN in google cloud with tensorflow, and my tf.record is huge, and It's going to take a long time to upload, Can I train without uploading my data to the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no. Training needs to be done with data, so you'll either need to do the training where the data is or put the data where the training will be. Having the data somewhere else won't be helpful, except for validating a model that's already been trained.